# WordPress Add custom column to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a post voting plugin in WordPress and a custom post type. Now, I am trying to add a Votes column to my custom post type which show total number of votes of that post.Before that I have tried it on WordPress default Post and it worked but Its not working with custom post type.

In functions.php

```
// Customizing WordPress admin to show post votes

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'voteme_extra_post_columns' );
add_filter( 'manage_child_contest_clips_posts_columns','voteme_extra_post_columns' );
function voteme_extra_post_columns( $columns )
{
  $columns[ 'votemecount' ] = __( 'Votes' );
  return $columns;
}

function voteme_post_column_row( $column )
{
   if ( $column != 'votemecount' )
   return;

   global $post;
   $post_id = $post->ID;
   $votemecount = get_post_meta($post_id, '_votemecount', true) != '' ? 
     get_post_meta($post_id, '_votemecount', true) : '0';
   echo $votemecount;

}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'voteme_post_column_row', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'manage_child_contest_clips_posts_custom_column', 'voteme_post_column_row', 
10,2);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with "it's not working" what isn't working?

Comment: here the custom post type was not but Its resolved now:
add_filter( 'manage_child_contest_clips_posts_columns','voteme_extra_post_columns' );